# Camel Processing JSON Messages from RabbitMQ

Tags: java, json, scala, apache-camel, rabbitmq

I want to post a message in JSON format to RabbitMQ and have that message consumed successfully. I'm attempting to use Camel to integrate producers and consumers. However, I'm struggling to understand how to create a route to make this happen. I'm using JSON Schema to define the interface between the Producer and Consumer. My application creates JSON, converts it to a byte[] and a Camel ProducerTemplate is used to send the message to RabbitMQ. On the consumer end, the byte[] message needs to be converted to a String, then to JSON, and then marshalled to an Object so I can process it. The following code line doesn't work however

```
from(startEndpoint).transform(body().convertToString()).marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, classOf[Payload]).bean(classOf[JsonBeanExample]),
```

It's as if the bean is passed the original byte[] content and not the object created by JSON `json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, classOf[Payload])`. All the camel examples I've seen which use the json(..) call seem be followed by a to(..) which is the end of the route? Here is the error message

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: uk.co.techneurons.messaging.Payload but has value: [B@48898819 of type: byte[] on: Message: "{\"id\":1}". Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: byte[] to the required type:     uk.co.techneurons.messaging.Payload with value [B@48898819. Exchange[ID-Tonys-    iMac-local-54996-1446407983661-0-2][Message: "{\"id\":1}"]. Caused by:     [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: byte[] to the required type: uk.co.techneurons.messaging.Payload with value [B@48898819]`
```

I don't really want to use Spring, Annotations etc, would like to service activation as simple as possible.  Use Camel as much as possible

This is the producer

```
package uk.co.techneurons.messaging
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext

object RabbitMQProducer extends App {
   val camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext
   val rabbitMQEndpoint: String = "rabbitmq:localhost:5672/advert?autoAck=false&threadPoolSize=1&username=guest&password=guest&exchangeType=topic&autoDelete=false&declare=false"
   val rabbitMQRouteBuilder = new RouteBuilder() {
     override def configure(): Unit = {
       from("direct:start").to(rabbitMQEndpoint)
     }
   }
   camelContext.addRoutes(rabbitMQRouteBuilder)
   camelContext.start
   val producerTemplate = camelContext.createProducerTemplate
   producerTemplate.setDefaultEndpointUri("direct:start")
   producerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader("{\"id\":1}","rabbitmq.ROUTING_KEY","advert.edited")
  camelContext.stop
}
```

This is the consumer..

```
package uk.co.techneurons.messaging
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext
import org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.JsonLibrary

object RabbitMQConsumer extends App {
  val camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext
  val startEndpoint = "rabbitmq:localhost:5672/advert?queue=es_index&exchangeType=topic&autoDelete=false&declare=false&autoAck=false"
  val consumer = camelContext.createConsumerTemplate
  val routeBuilder = new RouteBuilder() {
    override def configure(): Unit = {
        from(startEndpoint).transform(body().convertToString()).marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, classOf[Payload]).bean(classOf[JsonBeanExample])
    }
 }
 camelContext.addRoutes(routeBuilder)
 camelContext.start
 Thread.sleep(1000)
 camelContext.stop
}

case class Payload(id: Long)

class JsonBeanExample {
   def process(payload: Payload): Unit = {
     println(s"JSON ${payload}")
   }
}
```

For completeness, this is the sbt file for easy replication..

```
name := """camel-scala"""

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= {
 val scalaTestVersion = "2.2.4"
 val camelVersion: String = "2.16.0"
 val rabbitVersion: String = "3.5.6"
 val slf4jVersion: String = "1.7.12"
 val logbackVersion: String = "1.1.3"
 Seq(
   "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.3",
   "org.apache.camel" % "camel-core" % camelVersion,
   "org.apache.camel" % "camel-jackson" % camelVersion,
   "org.apache.camel" % "camel-scala" % camelVersion,
   "org.apache.camel" % "camel-rabbitmq" % camelVersion,
   "com.rabbitmq" % "amqp-client" % rabbitVersion,
   "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % slf4jVersion,
   "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % logbackVersion,
   "org.apache.camel" % "camel-test" % camelVersion % "test",
   "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % scalaTestVersion % "test")
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided that I needed to create a Bean and Register it (easier said than done! - for some as yet unknown reason JNDIRegistry didn't work with DefaultCamelContext  - so I used a SimpleRegistry),

```
  val registry: SimpleRegistry  = new SimpleRegistry()
  registry.put("myBean", new JsonBeanExample())
  val camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(registry)
```

Then I changed the consuming routeBuilder - seems like I had been over transforming the message.

```
  from(startEndpoint).unmarshal.json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, classOf[Payload]).to("bean:myBean?method=process")
```

I also changed the Bean so setter methods were available, and added a toString

```
class Payload {
   @BeanProperty var id: Long = _
   override def toString = s"Payload($id)"
} 
class JsonBeanExample() {
  def process(payload: Payload): Unit = {
     println(s"recieved ${payload}")
  }
}
```

The next problem now is to get dead letter queues working, and ensuring that failures in the Bean handler make their way properly back up the stack